# How to loop on a resource type multiple times in v3.8?

Tags: puppet

I have a Puppet manifest with three `exec` resources:

```
exec { 'test1':
  command     => "bla1",
  require     => File['test'],
}

exec { 'test2':
  command     => "bla2",
  require     => File['test'],
}

exec { 'test3':
  command     => "bla3",
  require     => File['test'],
}
```

Can someone offer a way to improve the code, such as with a loop?

I'm using Puppet 3.8 and would need something supported in that release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
  $cmd = [
    "command1",
    "command2",
    "command3",
  ]

  define run_command {
    exec { "${name}":
      path    => ['/usr/bin','/usr/sbin','/bin','/sbin'],
    }
  }
  run_command { $cmd: 
      require => File['test'];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate please how does it actually work to resolve command1, command2, command3 to ${name} ?